# Wordpress - run query when plugin is activated

Tags: wordpress

I'm not a Wordpress fa, at all...but a client asked me to realize a new site using this CMS so I started from scratch reading: https://codex.wordpress.org

I need to create a table when the users activate the plugin, I have followed all the documentation reported above but I'm not able to run a CREATE TABLE.

Here my code:

```
// Indico il nome della funzione da eseguire all'attivazione del plugin 
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'schede_eccellenze_plugin_install'); 

function schede_eccellenze_plugin_install()
{
    global $wpdb;

    //Elenco dei nomi delle tabelle da creare
    $tabella_alberghi = $wpdb->prefix."schede_eccellenze_alberghi";

    //Query tabella per le stanze
    $sql_albergo = "
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ". $tabella_alberghi ." (
            id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            descrizione TEXT NOT NULL,
            indirizzo TEXT NOT NULL,
        );
    ";

    //Recupero il file necessario per la creazione e aggiornamento tabelle
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');

    //Eseguio le query di creazione
    dbDelta($sql_albergo);

}
```

What's wrong with my code? Every time I run the activation it doesn't run the query.

EDIT:
I need to create a plugin that allow my client to insert differend type of thing such as:

1. List of hotels
2. List of local food&wine bar
3. etc

The purpose of this plugin is to give to him an interface to insert data and the possibility to edit or delete the entries.
I think to create a table for each type of entry (each entry has different fields and so different column) to keep data separate.
Currently I have no idea how many types of things he needs

Comment: I know this doesn't really answer the question - but can you explain why you want to create a new table? There are a lot of ways to store data using WordPress so it isn't advisable in most cases to bypass WordPress this way...

Comment: I have no idea how to store data with wordpress, can you please give me some docs about it?

Comment: Well that depends. Please explain your use case, then we can give you appropriate advice.

Comment: Okay as I guessed - what you are looking for are [Custom Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types), maybe combined with [Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields). This helps storing custom data while still using WordPress. This doesn't create custom tables, but still is the way such things are meant to be done in WordPress.

Comment: @kraftner is correct, try this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui